# PuTTY script reading a list?

Tags: script, putty, redhat-enterprise-linux

Is there a way in PuTTY to run a script that will read a file of names and then answer a prompt of yes (per name)?

It is a Red Hat Linux backend server that I am connecting too.

At times I can get a list of over 100 names, and I have to do them one by one.

In batch it may be something like below
for /F "tokens=*" %%A in (myfile.txt) do [process] %%A echo y

or maybe in shell
#!/bin/bash

```
 input_file=server.csv
      
 echo "ServerName" 
 
 tail -n +2 "$input_file" | while IFS=, read -r server name _
 do
    if  acli snapshot.delete -c 3 "$ServerName" > /dev/null; then echo Y
       
    else
        server_delete="FAIL"
done
```

Comment: Putty is the terminal client that you use to make the connection and run the terminal session.  Once in the session you have a shell that you interact with for running commands.  It's probably the case that the shell you're using is bash, is that right?  If so you're looking for a bash script and not a Putty script.

Comment: Based on your edit you're obviously not looking for a bash script.  Are you looking for automation so that Putty itself can respond to bash prompts?  Sorry, just trying to undertand your request.